# Ajuda no plugin YTPlayer

Tags: jquery, youtube

Preciso de ajuda com o plugin mb.YTPlayer.

Eu estou a usar este plugin, contudo se o link do video do youtube contiver um `-`, o plugin ja não funciona.

Como posso fazer para que funcione?

Comment: É **[este](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer)** o plugin?

Comment: Sim é esse mesmo, o link não funciona

Comment: Eu experimentei colocar um `id` de um link de um video com `-` e o video funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Sim já funciona corretamente, devia de ser da net e o video não estar a carregar, obrigado pela ajuda.